# mysql python multiprocessing pool issues

Tags: python-multiprocessing, mysql-python

Error I keep getting:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

My code:

```
def runDBQuery(bl_sel):
    dbResponse = []
    bl_cur.execute(bl_sel)
    myresult2 = bl_cur.fetchall()
    dbResponse.append(myresult2)
    return(dbResponse)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1abl_sel = bl_sel_template.replace("{firstupc}",p1afirstupc).replace("{lastupc}",p1alastupc)
    p2abl_sel = bl_sel_template.replace("{firstupc}",p2afirstupc).replace("{lastupc}",p2alastupc)
    list_of_columns = [ p1abl_sel, p2abl_sel ]
    #list_of_columns = [ p1abl_sel ]
    p = Pool(processes=2)
    data = p.map(runDBQuery, [i for i in list_of_columns])
    # the 4 lines below are my failed attempts to try to resolve this. 
    bl_cur.close()
    if cur and con:
        cur.close()
        con.close()
    p.close()
    print(data)
```

Whenever I uncomment the `list_of_columns` so there's only one element(query) in the list, it works and I get back a response from the DB.  However, if I have more than one element in the list, I encounter the listed error.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be not in your code.

MySQL error **"Lost connection to MySQL server during query"** can accrue because of reading timeout. It can be either on the client side or mysql server configuration

MySQL

- **max_execution_time**: The execution timeout for SELECT statements, in milliseconds. If the value is 0, timeouts are not enabled.
- **connect_timeout**: Number of seconds the mysqld server waits for a connect packet before responding with 'Bad handshake'
- **interactive_timeout** Number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive connection before closing it
- **wait_timeout** Number of seconds the server waits for activity on a connection before closing it

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time

For pyMysql check **read_timeout**

https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html

Comment: i dont know what to make of this.  It does appear to me that the problem is in my code. What I'm trying to do here is query the mysql database simultaneously.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I just recommended You to check DB config first